# Other functions with sigmoid shape

Tags: modeling, function

Apart from the classic logistic or sigmoid function, are there other **interesting** functions that map real x into a positive space? Maybe they also have an S shape.

Maybe inspired by some nature modeling.

Comment: “into a positive space”—is this your only requirement? This includes the exponential function. There’s also the inverse probit function (along with several other real cdfs) and translations of the tanh function. In general it’s easy to construct these. Is there a constraint missing in your question?

Comment: What makes a function interesting? I think the core of OP's question is answered in the duplicate thread. If OP disagrees, please [edit] the question to clarify.